# Postgres Query with Regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to create a regex to find (and then eventually replace) parts of strings in a PG DB. I'm using PSQL 9.0.4

I've tested my regex outside of PG and it works perfectly. However, it isn't playing well with PG. If anyone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong it would me much appreciated.

Regex:

```
{php}.*\n.*\n.*'mister_xx']\)\);.*\n} \n{\/php}
```

Postgres Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM "Table" WHERE "Column" ~ '{php}.*\n.*\n.*'mister_xx']\)\);.*\n} \n{\/php}') as x;
```

Postgres Response:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: ...M (SELECT * FROM "Table" WHERE "Column" ~ '{php}.*\n...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "mister_xx"
LINE 1: ..."Table" WHERE "Column" ~ '{php}.*\n.*\n.*'mister_x...
```

Comment: You need to escape single quotes around `mister_xx` in your query.

Comment: I've tried that, sadly it returns the same error.

Comment: I also tried escaping the { and } characters

Comment: Try to start from something simple. Like `WHERE "Column" ~ '.*''mister_xx''.*'`. It will find you any text, that has `'mister_xx'` in it. Then just buid up your regexp from that point.

Comment: Your current regexp has too many errors to fix them at once.

Comment: actually, there was only issue with the regex, and it was with the ) characters I included in my search. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, quotes are delimited as two quotes, for example:

```
'Child''s play'
```

Applying this to your regex makes it work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "Table"
WHERE "Column" ~ '{php}.*\n.*\n.*''mister_xx'']\)\);.*\n} \n{\/php}' as x;
```

Note also how the redundant subquery .

Answer (score 1):

You need to double escape the backslashes and add an E before the statement:
SELECT * FROM "Table" WHERE "Column" ~ E'{php}*\n.*\n.*''mister_xx'']\)\);.*\n} \n{\/php}'